# FullCalender: Set/change the duration of an event by dragging

Tags: fullcalendar

I've looking through the docs and source code of FullCalender but since this is my first time looking at it, there's a lot to go through so before i get too involved i'd like to know when you drag an event to the calender, if it's possible to place the events on the calender to more specific times? For example maybe i want to attend at meeting at 10.08 but calender initially only allows me to put the events at times with a 30 min interval, 10 o'clock, 10.30 o'clock, 11 o'clock etc. The 30-min interval limitation also goes for resizing(changing the duration) the event when its dropped onto the calender.

Calender with an event added:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJuhQ.jpg (cant post images cus not enough rep)

And if so, what variable am I to look at in the code?

Side note: This is my first time working with java script

Answer (score 0):

"slotDuration" is the variable to look for when initializing the Calender it seems like. Now I can move drag and drop the events like i wanted to kinda even though i have to do a lot of scrolling to navigate through the 24 hours of one day

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        slotDuration: '00:01:00',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        drop: function() {
```